# SQL Server 2008 R2 Quiet Installation Failure

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, 64-bit

I've downloaded the SQL Server 2008 R2 software from Microsoft and am working on scripting a silent installation.  I'm getting the following errors (and the duplicate paste job is not an accident, that's how it shows up for me)

```
The following error occurred:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Error result: 1152035024
Result facility code: 1194
Result error code: 43216

Please review the summary.txt log for further details
The following error occurred:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Error result: 1152035024
Result facility code: 1194
Result error code: 43216

Please review the summary.txt log for further details
Microsoft (R) SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup 10.50.1600.01
```

This is what shows up in the detailed SQL install log.

```
2011-02-23 09:53:13 Slp: Running Action: ExecuteInitWorkflow
2011-02-23 09:53:13 Slp: Workflow to execute: 'INITIALIZATION'
2011-02-23 09:53:13 Slp: Error: Action "Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.BootstrapExtension.ExecuteWorkflowAction" threw an exception during execution.
2011-02-23 09:53:13 Slp: Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionExecutionException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
2011-02-23 09:53:13 Slp: Parameter name: InstallMediaPath
```

Hopefully someone can help me work through this.  Here is a simple version of my PowerShell code.

```
$arguments = @()
$arguments += "/q"
$arguments += "/ACTION=Install"
$arguments += "/FEATURES=SQL,Tools"
$arguments += "/INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER"
$arguments += "/SQLSVCACCOUNT=`"$NetBIOSDomainName\$SQLServerServiceAccount`""
$arguments += "/SQLSVCPASSWORD=`"$SQLServerServiceAccountPassword`""
$arguments += "/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=`"$NetBIOSDomainName\$SQLSysAdminAccount`""
$arguments += "/AGTSVCACCOUNT=`"$NetBIOSDomainName\$SQLServerAgentAccount`""
$arguments += "/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS"
Start-Process "$SQLServerSetupLocation\setup.exe" -Wait -ArgumentList $arguments -RedirectStandardOutput error.txt
```

Comment: I torched my answer since it was obvious that wasn't your problem...  Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my issue ended up being that I wasn't using the -WorkingDirectory parameter of the Start-Process cmdlet.  The setup.exe file calls all kinds of processes as part of the installation and I think the child processes that it was calling weren't aware of the correct "WorkingDirectory."  The code that works is as follows.

```
Start-Process "$SQLServerSetupLocation\setup.exe" -Wait -WorkingDirectory $SQLServerSetupLocation -ArgumentList $arguments
```